# java console does not update with the changes in my source code

Tags: java, eclipse, build, console

I am trying to set up a java project and so far everything is working as one can see in this screenshot:

[image]

However when i adjust my code, the console does not update as wel as we can see here:[image]

I tried to check path -> build automatically and clean the project but this does not work. I also terminated the console and restarted it but this did not help as well. Anyone can help me with this problem?

Kees

Comment: Did you do both a Clean and a Build?

Comment: Did you clear the console? (The double X in the upper right hand corner)

Comment: thanks for the fast responses. I did clear the console (remove launch / remove all terminated launches) and i cleaned the project in the project -> clean section. What do you mean by a build?

Comment: Also, did you Run the project or file?  A project might *Build* automatically, but it won't run.  You have to manually chose Run to get it to execute and give you new console output.

Comment: @markspace i tried both by rightclicking on the files and run them as java applications. Both gave me the same output

Comment: When I run a file, I pick "Run File" off the right click menu.  Or I pick "Run Project" from the main (top) menu.  They're different things.  I don't use Eclipse but I think it's similar.  Stick to "Run File" for now, try to get that one file to execute properly.  We'll debug your project as a whole after the one file is working.

Comment: @markspace i did something very stupid, Eclipse does not automatically save your file thus it did not update my source file all this time. I feel so stupid right now xD.

Comment: It looks like your file is not saved. Note the * in the tab with the filename *Training1.java. Try to save the file, build, and then run again.

Comment: That's a bit weird.  Just to plug a different IDE, NetBeans sensibly saves your file first when you chose "Run File" from the right click menu.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was actually quite easy. I assumed Eclipse automatically saves your changes when re-running the console but this was not true. Thus when i just save the file it runs perfectly fine. Can't believe I spend a hour not figuring this out.

Kees

Comment: You can have it automatically save for you before you run or debug. Check the Launching preference page. http://help.eclipse.org/2018-09/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/preferences/run-debug/ref-launching.htm?cp=1_4_2_1_1.